# Permutation Formula

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am having difficulty with one minuscule detail of the permutation formula:

$$n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)$$

I understand that if we proceed with an $r$-permutation, then we have $r$ amount of slots, where the first slot has a total of $n$ ways of being occupied by a single object, from a set of n objects; similarly, for the second slot, we have one less object from the total amount (because one has already been selected for the first slot), meaning we $n-1$ amount of ways to select a single object for it. I also understand that as you go down the line of slots, there are less and less objects available to select for a particular slot that is relatively far from the first slot. My question is, **why does the amount of decrease such that the  last slot has a total of $n-r+1$ ways to select an object for that slot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permutation formula is $$P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)(n-r)(n-r-1)\cdots2\cdot1}{(n-r)(n-r-1)\cdots2\cdot1}$$

This is why the last slot is $(n-r+1)$.
 Think of it in concrete terms. I have 8 objects, and I want to take 4 of those objects and see how many permutations I can generate with those 4 objects.  So $n=8$ and $r=4$.  Thus, the number of ways I can do it is $$8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$$
What is 5?  It is $8-4+1$...

Comment: Why do you write things like $8*7*6*5$ instead of $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$ or $8\times7\times6\times5$?  The whole point of using an asterisk is that one is limited to the characters on the keyboard, so that things like $\times$ are not available, and one want to avoid using $x$ instead of $\times$ because the letter $x$ should be available for other uses.  And the whole point of $\TeX$ is to make things like $8\cdot7$ and $8\times7$ available.  Using an asterisk for ordinary multiplication in $\TeX$ amounts to eating mashed potatoes with your hands when silverware is available.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, sorry.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend, I was just trying to answer the question.  I will keep your comment in mind from here on in and have good formatting!

Comment: To read postings on math.stackexchange.com is to learn that some people have limited knowledge of $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$.  (My own knowledge of those is quite limited, but I try to be aware of standard conventions.)

Comment: I appreciate the heads up.  I suppose in math since rigor is preferred the same applies to the language here.  Thanks.